# Multiplying an array with a single value by a number?

Tags: javascript

Why does JavaScript allow you to multiply arrays with a single numeric value by another numeric value or by another array with a single numeric value?:

```
[3] * 3;
// 9

[3] * 2;
// 6

[3] * [3];
// 9

[1, 2] * 2
// NaN
```

I would expect `NaN` to be returned every time but as my experiments in Chrome have demonstrated this is not the case.

Is this the expected behavior? Does this behavior make sense? If so, why?

Comment: I think that http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXEgk1Hdze0 is the only possible answer here :)

Answer (score 10):

```
[3] * 3;
```

The following steps are taken:

- array is converted to a string `[3] => "3"`
- the string is converted to a number `Number("3") => 3`
- `3 * 3` gives `9`

Similarly, for `[1, 2] * 2`:

- array is converted to a string `[1, 2] => ""1,2"`
- the string is converted to a number `Number("1,2") => NaN`
- `NaN * 3` gives `NaN`

For ECMA freaks among us ;) start [here](http://es5.github.io/#x11.5) and follow the path `multiplicative operator => ToNumber => ToPrimitive => [[DefaultValue]](number) => valueOf => toString`

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. ... In the context of my _.clone method where I noticed this behavior, it seems undesired (perhaps not, I'm undecided): `_.clone([1, 2, [3]], function(num) { return num * 2; })` where a callback is applied to each value and so the returned result is `[2, 4, 6]`. ... I don't want to fight against the language I'm using but in this case the result of this behavior seems like trouble. What do you think?

Comment: @Xaxis: I don't understand what `clone` means here. Is it `map`? In any case, JS is weakly-typed, if you want to enforce strict typing, add explicit type checking: `if(typeof x == number)... else throw(...)`

Comment: My `clone` method makes a deep copy of an array or object with the option of calling a callback on each value. ... Yes, I'm well aware I can perform type checking but that would limit the methods callback to only working on values that are numbers. ... Anyway, I appreciate the feedback greatly!

Comment: @Xaxis: if this is the case, I'd expect the result of `clone([1,2,[3]])` to be `[2,4,[6]]`, with the callback being called on each _primitive_ value.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening here is that `[3]` is being coerced into a `String` type, which is just `"3"`. Then in `"3" * 3` the `String` value `"3"` gets converted into the number `3`. You finally end up with `3 * 3`, which evaluates to `9`.

You can see this behavior if you do `[3].toString() * 3` or `"3" * 3`, which also gives you `9`,

So the following steps happen:

- `[3] * 3`
- `[3].toString() * 3`
- `"3" * 3`
- `Number("3") * 3`
- `3 * 3`
- `9`

In the case `[1, 2]`, you eventually end up with `"1, 2"`. But `Number("1, 2")` results in a `NaN` and a number multiplied with a `NaN` results in `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.2

Since Array.prototype.valueOf is not available, it falls back to using the String version (as per http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9)

The toString renders an array with a single element as the value of the element (so [3].toString() is 3)

Answer (score 0):

//Say to increase each element by 10%, we may use the following:

```
let arr=[];
let array = [100, 200, 500, 1000];
array.forEach((p,i)=>arr[i]=(p*110/100));
console.log(arr);
```

//expected [110,220,550,1100]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Which was about why `[3]*3` works while `[1,2]*3` doesn't. Not about how to make them work.