# Multiply a number to an array

Tags: javascript

From the following thread ([Multiplying an array with a single value by a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301934/multiplying-an-array-with-a-single-value-by-a-number)) I got the information that it is not possible to multiply a number to all elements within an array by executing `[1, 2]*3`. But since I have to do this I was wondering if there is an smart way of doing this?

I know I could write a function which iterates through all elements and multiply a number to each element manually. But I was wondering if there is a smarter way out there?

Maybe there are some libraries out there which implements some math functions where I can multiply a number to all elements of an array?

Or do you think the map function of Array can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed use the `map` function:

```
function multiply(input) {
    return input * 3;
}

var myArray = [1, 2];
var myNewArray = myArray.map(multiply);
```

What this does is perform a function you provide on each element in the array, and return a new array with the results.

If you're already using jQuery, you can make it a little more concise with the `each` function:

```
$.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
    myArray[index] = value * 3;
});
```

This changes the existing array. Although, using the plain-JS approach, you could do `myArray = myArray.map(multiply);` if you don't want a new variable.

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8NdX/) as an example.

Comment: ok, thanks and what if want to multiply an array with any given number?

Comment: @Christoph If you want any given number you can do something like this: `var myNewArray = myArray.map(function(input){return input * 3});` you can change 3 to whatever you want it to multiply with.

Comment: You could just put the multiplier in a variable and fill the variable with whatever the number should be (could be an ajax call, value in input field, etc). See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8NdX/2/) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with a library like [math.js](http://mathjs.org), which comes with matrix support. You could do something like:

```
var result = math.multiply([1, 2], 3);
```

or using the expression parser:

```
var result = math.eval('[1, 2] * 3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Jos de Jong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17655882/150884), if you are using [numericjs](http://www.numericjs.com/) you can do

```
var result = numeric.mul([1, 2], 3);
```

To give the result `[3, 6]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined your array as an array variable: Just do as following:

```
function times2(theArray){
 var newArray = [];
 for (i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(theArray[i] * 2);
 }
 return newArray;
}
document.write("Array double = ",times2([1,2,3,4,5]).toString() , "<br>");
```

Now it does not matter how many elements you have in your array, it multiplies them by 2. You can choose any number instead of 2.